# Cannot connect to OpenVPN/BolehVPN: Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to connect to my VPN service, which is BolehVPN (uses openVPN I think, not positive how that works). I just can't get connected. BolehVPN customer service checked my configurations and said they all look right and to check the syslogs. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the Linux client?

Comment: You have to give us more details. How are you trying to connect? CLI? NM GUI? Using a .ovpn script? Any specific error messages? Etc.